# Angular-pdf-viewer not working after grunt build

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, web, gruntjs

I'm using angular-pdf-viewer (sorry I cannot put more than 2 links, you'll find it here : github.com/winkerVSbecks/angular-pdf-viewer) to view a PDF in my angular website. It works perfectly on my local server but fails after "grunt build" and copying the dist folder on my server.

Here is my github : https://github.com/kalaspa/SywocClient/tree/master/app

Here is what grunt build tells me : http://pastebin.com/En8vRsZV

It is not a problem about the URL toward the document since the download button works.

I've been playing with my Gruntfile for hours and I can't make things right. I started my project with yeoman, installed bower components using the ""--save"" option, so it should work properly.

I'm a bit in a hurry since some hackers hacked the old website this afternoon before I finished this one. I was given an obsolete website.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found here : https://github.com/winkerVSbecks/angular-pdf-viewer/issues/6

This library needs you to add to your bower.json :

```
    "overrides": {
      "pdfjs-dist": {
        "main": [
           "build/pdf.js",
           "build/pdf.worker.js",
           "build/pdf.combined.js"
          ]
       }
    }
```

Took me all an afternoon to find as it is not in the documentation. Hope it will help others with the same problem